# Installing a R package in Docker ends with Package not found

Tags: r, docker

I build a simple docker with the R sf package, whatever I try ends up with the message that the package is not found. Please find below the various attempts:

trial 1

```
FROM rocker/r-apt:bionic
RUN R -e "install.packages('sf');     if (!library(sf, logical.return=T)) quit(status=10)"
```

trial 2

```
FROM rocker/r-apt:bionic
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install libgdal-dev
RUN R -e "install.packages('sf',dependencies=TRUE);     if (!library(sf, logical.return=T)) quit(status=10)"
```

trial 3

```
FROM rocker/r-apt:bionic
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install libgdal-dev
RUN mkdir -p R-lib
RUN R -e "install.packages('sf',lib='R-lib', dependencies=TRUE);     if (!library(sf, lib.loc='R-lib', logical.return=T)) quit(status=10)"
```

trial 4

```
FROM rocker/r-apt:bionic
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install libgdal-dev
RUN mkdir -p R-lib
RUN R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/sf_1.0-15.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source', lib='R-lib'); if (!library(sf, , lib='R-lib', logical.return=T)) quit(status=10)"
```

They all end with

```
1530.8 In library(sf, lib.loc = "R-lib", logical.return = T) :
1530.8   there is no package called ‘sf’
```

after a list of dependencies errors:

```
1529.4 ERROR: dependencies ‘leaflet’, ‘raster’, ‘sf’ are not available for package ‘leafem’
1529.4 * removing ‘/R-lib/leafem’
1529.7 ERROR: dependency ‘leaflet’ is not available for package ‘leafsync’
1529.7 * removing ‘/R-lib/leafsync’
1530.1 ERROR: dependencies ‘leafem’, ‘leaflet’, ‘leafpop’, ‘raster’, ‘satellite’, ‘sf’ are not available for package ‘mapview’
1530.1 * removing ‘/R-lib/mapview’
1530.7 ERROR: dependencies ‘tmaptools’, ‘sf’, ‘stars’, ‘units’, ‘leaflet’, ‘leafsync’, ‘leafem’ are not available for package ‘tmap’
1530.7 * removing ‘/R-lib/tmap’
```

Which I don't understand, given that the dependencies=TRUE should have taken care of that.
I am running out of idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'bionic' (aka 18.04) release is old and no longer supported for binaries.

If you try `rocker/r2u`, which is supported for 'focal' (20.04) or 'jammy' (22.04), you are guaranteed success.  I would pick 'jammy'.

For me, `time docker run --rm -ti rocker/r2u Rscript -e 'install.packages("sf")'` completes in 18 seconds, installing 66 packages with `sf` via `r-cran-sf` being the final one.

Comment: It works, does not need dependencies and is much much faster,

Comment: I’ve always built from source on Ubuntu. Gives you more informative errors when dependencies are not met.

Comment: @IRTFM We all have our ways, but every now and then new shortcuts appear and are worth exploring.  r2u is honestly good and worth trying.

Comment: @AdaLovelace ; Love your moniker. 16 seconds is admittedly much faster than compiling the full list of dependencies for pkg:sf. Might take a half hour on my 2018 box. (I wasn’t trying to be critical. I was one of the upvoters. ) Docker might be worth a try.

Comment: @IRTFM  Docker is the easiest way to take advantage of `r2u` but it works everywhere Ubuntu works:  laptop, server, AWS instance, GitHub runner, ...  And is used in all those because ... "sixteen seconds without errors" is indeed nice.